# Javascript loop for the google maps markers

Tags: javascript, loops, google-maps

I am trying to create a simple google map with markers and loop through the source of the markers data.

If I exchange the key.lng or key.lat in following code with hardcoded values, everything works fine.
new google.maps.LatLng(key.lng,key.lat)

```js
//just as an example of data, will be changed to real source of JSON file and loaded properly
 var jsonObj = [
{
  "lng": 18.773801,
  "lat": 49.226598,
  "cty": "LO"
 },{
  "lng": 19.083882,
  "lat": 48.751877,
  "cty": "LO"
 }];
 
  
 var string = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
 var loadedData = JSON.parse(string);
 
 var stationsList = [];
 
 loadedData.forEach(function(key, index){
   //THIS WORKS
    //stationsList = appendObjTo(stationsList, {position: new google.maps.LatLng(19.083882,48.751877), type: 'station'});
  //THIS NOT
    stationsList = stationsList.concat({position: new google.maps.LatLng(key.lng,key.lat), type: 'station'});
 });
```

Comment: What is the problem right now?

Comment: `THIS NOT` - why not? error in the browser developer console? as long as `new google.maps.LatLng` works, your code works just fine - what the heck is `appendObjTo` function?

Comment: what if you do `var stationsList = loadedData.map(key =>({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(key.lng, key.lat),
    type: 'station'
  }));` instead

Comment: why to stringify then parse,  you can directly loop over the jsonObj .. arghhhhh !!

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui - at a guess, the *actual* code parses a JSON response, rather than declares a (nothing to do with JSON) JS object - the comment *will be changed to real source of JSON file and loaded properly* suggests this is the case

Comment: 27 minutes ago you were asked "what is the problem" ... saying "this doesn't work" is meaningless ... in what way does it not work? errors? or as the answer below suggests, the markers are in the wrong location (which means "THIS WORKS" was incorrect information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching paramters from

```
new google.maps.LatLng(key.lng,key.lat)
```

to

```
new google.maps.LatLng(key.lat,key.lng)
```

Latitude is first argument in constructor

Comment: but hardcoded `new google.maps.LatLng(19.083882,48.751877)` **works** - it too would be in the wrong location :p (I think the OP has left the building)

Comment: Thank you so much, I just could not find it :(